# How Does the Browser Insert HTML and Header?

Tags: html, webstorm

I created an HTML file in Webstorm my-file.html

```
<body>
    hi
</body>
```

I notice the browser inserts the html and head tags

[image]

How and why does the browser insert that?

Comment: An HTML page should have a doctype, an `html` element, a `head` element, and a `body` element. The doctype is *technically* optional, but it should always be included to prevent unwanted behavior (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Quirks_Mode_and_Standards_Mode).

Comment: So is chrome just inserting that on my behalf if I fail to specify it?

Comment: Yes, a good browser will attempt to forgive many sins, such as improperly nested or unclosed tags. The why is primarily to improve the experience for the user. The how isn't really suitable for this venue.

Answer (score 2):

Modern browsers follow the parsing algorithm described in the [HTML living standard](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/parsing.html), which is highly tolerant of errors. It will automatically insert required tags, missing closing tags, and so on, if they're missing. For example:

```html
<title>title</title>
<p>para
```

Parses to the following DOM elements:

```html
<html><head><title>title</title>
</head><body><p>para</p></body></html>
```

### Demo

```js
const textarea = document.querySelector('textarea')

const update = () => {
    const parser = new DOMParser()
    const doc = parser.parseFromString(textarea.value, 'text/html')

    document.querySelector('pre').textContent =
        doc.documentElement.outerHTML
}

textarea.addEventListener('input', update)
update()
```

```css
textarea { width: 100%; min-height: 100px; }
```

```html
<textarea><title>Edit me!</title>
<p>para</textarea>

<pre></pre>
```